# Return false to a function with a callback as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a function that call another function in this way:

```
f.callApi({call: 'route'}, function(response){
    f.drawRoute(response.points);
});
```

The function called is the following:

```
...

callApi: function(option, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        success: function(response){ callback(response) }
    });
}
...
```

This works just fine.

The problem is that I want to introduce a condition where the ajax call is not made because it doesn't fit the prerequisites to do the AJAX call.

So what I'm trying to do is to to return false as a response.

```
...

callApi: function(option, callback){
    if(conditionNotMet){
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        success: function(response){ callback(response) }
    });
}
...
```

This doesn't seem to work, I think I am missing to understand how exactly the AJAX success call works.

I'm not sure whether I should be returning a function, or how to make the response parameter false for the callback.

To be more clear, I mean that response should be false:

```
f.callApi({call: 'route'}, function(response){
    console.log(response); //This should be false.
});
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @SLaks please look at my edit to see if my intention is more clear.

Comment: `callback(false);` instead

Comment: If you want to call the callback, you need to call the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from what i understand you simply want :

```
callApi: function(option, callback){
    if(conditionNotMet) callback(false);
    else $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        success: function(response){ callback(response) }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly now :), that was pretty clear but I was seriously blocked!